# Use returned value from query in the a where clause for another select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables both shown below.

**tblId**:

```
Id      Name
1A      James
23      Holly
33      Rob
```

**tblData**:

```
Date          Score     Name
2016-06-01    3.5       James
2016-06-01    4.5       Holly
2016-06-01    5.5       Rob
2016-06-01    2.5       James
2016-06-01    3.5       Holly
2016-06-01    6.5       Rob
...
2016-06-01    7.5       James
2016-06-01    11.5      Holly
2016-06-01    1.5       Rob
```

I have written the query below but it doesn't like the tick.Name bit saying multi-part identifier could not be bound.

I know that only one record will ever be returned by the

```
select Name 
from tblId 
where Id = 33
```

query. What is the best way to use this value in the where part of my next select statement?

```
;with tick as
(
    select Name from tblId where Id = 33
)
select Date, Score 
from tblData
where Name = tick.Name and Date >= '2016-06-01'
order by Date
```

Comment: You have to select from tick, the cte is "available" but not selected from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered a `join`?

```
with tick as (
    select Name from tblId where Id = 33
   )
select t.Date, t.Score
from tblData t join
     tick
     on t.name = tick.name
where t.Date >= '2016-06-01'
order by t.Date
```

Comment: oh yeh that was pretty stupid of me... been a long day but thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
select Date, Score from tblData td
where EXISTS (select 1 from tblId  t where t.Id = 33 AND td.Name = t.Name )
and Date >= '2016-06-01'
order by Date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Date, Score from tblData
 where Name in (select Name from tblId where Id = 33) 
   and Date >= '2016-06-01'
 order by Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using a variable instead of a CTE since you're selecting from another table by its ID, which will give you only one value always.